# Need help in framing the generic linear equations with following constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have a binary variable array: $Y(i,j)$. Where $i=1,\dots,I$ and $j=1,\dots,K$. Here $K$ and $I$ need not to be same. In other words, the matrix formed $Y(i,j)$ is not necessarily be a squared ( but it can be).

Let us take an example of $Y$ as follows: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

We can see that $I=3$ and $K=12$. Let us assume that $j=1,2$ are from $group \space A$ and $j=3$ is from $group \space B$

**Condition 1:** Only $j=1,5,9,\dots$ positions will have either $0$ or $1$. Rest will only have $0$. **Except for following condition**

**Condition 2:** If $Y(i,j)$ is $1$ for elements in $group \space A$ and $group \space B$ simultaneously, then  $Y(i \in group \space A , group \space B ,j=j+1)$ should also be $1$.

For example:

$Y(1,1)$ and $Y(3,1)$ are $1$. Thus, $Y(1,2)$ and $Y(3,2)$ are also $1$.

**Condition 3:** If multiple $Y(i,j)$ from same groups are $1$ for same $j$, then **Condition 2** does not hold true.

For example,

$Y(1,9)$ and $Y(2,9)$ are $1$. But $Y(1,10)$ and $Y(2,10)$ are NOT $1$.

How to write a set of generic linear equations in terms of :

- Groups : $Group \space A ,Group \space B, \dots$
- $i: 1,\dots,I$
- $j: 1,\dots,K$

Comment: Your first condition is not really clear to me. What do you mean by *$j = 1, 5, 9, ...$ positions will have either 0 or 1*?

Comment: $j=1,5,9,\dots$ means the gap of $4$ in this particular case. However, I am looking for generic. Where this gap can be even $0$. So, even if conditions 2 & 3 are not followed, these positions can take $0$ or $1$. Rest positions can (or cannot) take 1, based on remaining conditions.